# Injecting First Angular Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, factory

I'm way overdue for injecting my first angular Factory . . .

My code:

```
.factory('Debts', function($q, $scope){
     return MA;
 })

.controller('Admin', function ($scope, Debts) {
      $scope.Debts = Debts;
      $scope.Debts.MA();
})
```

With $scope in my factory I get the following error:
Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- Debts

I read somewhere that we should not include $scope in the factory but when I take it out I get two errors:

1) Provider 'Debts' must return a value from $get factory method
2) `Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`

The code for my factory is several hundred lines and yes it references $scope and $q. Please let me know what I need to change to make this work.

Comment: What is 'MA' which you write as return value in Depts factory code?

Comment: What is `MA`? And you shouldn't use `$scope` in a service. You'll have to refactor to not use it.

Comment: I can take $scope out. MA is an array of objects. What about the other error regarding $get

Comment: Could you give us example on plunker or something?

Comment: The `$scope` is available only for controllers and the link function of `directives`

Comment: BTW If 'MA' is an array object as you said, you can't call Depts.MA as function in your controller.

Comment: so I just use dot notation instead of ()?

Comment: Nope. 'Depts' is an array object because your Depts factory return an array object. Anyway please give us example on plunker or something.

Comment: What would be helpful to see on Plunker? I mean, what's missing.  Or what could be in the middle that's of consequence? The function was previously a function in a controller that worked just fine.  When I realized that I'd need to put in multiple controllers it I thought a factory would work.  It's a lot of stuff to try and put into a plunker so if you could help me understand what you're considering it would be helpful.  As I understand it, working functions are determined by what they're called (controller, directive, factory) and what they return.

Comment: I believe whole example could be always helpful to investigate problems. Plus it is useful to organize problems. I guess there is something you have not mentioned could cause your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$scope` is available only for `controllers` and the link function of `directives`. This is why the factory cannot find it. Maybe you meant `$rootScope`?

```
.factory('Debts', function($q, $rootScope){
     return MA;
 })
```

???

Comment: I'm still getting the $get factory method error. I was just told that I can't use $scope in a service . . . so which one is it? In this case it's minor in the factory and easily refactored.

Comment: yes, I"m still getting the $get factory method error. Help . . .